# Display different pages in Bootstrap nav tabs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Master page in Asp.net

```
 Default.Master
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table width="1340" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="tabs-table">
     <li><a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Login</a></li>
     <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Members</a></li>
     <li class="active"><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Search</a></li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="1">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Content PlacedHolder is not showing any content in my Login page

```
 Login.aspx

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" Inherits="GRCOM_Web_Admin.Login" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<p>This is Section 1</p>
   <div style="width: 100%">
    <asp:Label ID="Userlbl" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="Usertxtbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I ended up using 1 single Content Page for all the tabs i have.

```
 1. Master Page
 2. Content Page
 3. All the 3 tabs on Content Page and everything is working fine now.
```

I didnt find any way to have all the tree tabs on Master page and display three different content pages on the 3 different tabs.

Answer (score 1):

do you have closed tag of content place order?

```
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: OK guys here is the problem....

If i make login page as startup then its content are shown and not the other two tabs...
I make other Member page as startup then member content are shown.

Answer (score 1):

No 1 Check that you have mentioned  Master Page File in page

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/yourfile.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="yourloginfile.aspx.cs" Inherits="yourproject.file" culture="auto" %>
```

Then

```
   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterPageContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: All the tags are complete and ok...but still not able to view.

Comment: @Dot_NET Junior can you please edit your question and place complete minimum code so one would be able to figure out what you are doing. Thanks

Comment: I have a master tab with 3 tabs login Members and Search and I have 3 asp.net pages.

I want to display the 3 different pages in 3 different tabs inside master page. How can i do that.

Comment: @Dot_NET Junior please check about how to add user controls they will solve your this query i believe

Comment: @Dot_NET Junior I got your point now you have three links in master page and once you click on any link you want to show content at the master page rather than on any other separate page ? Is it the problem ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45910/discussion-between-afnan-ahmad-and-dot-net-junior)